# Strange behavior of SQL Server - random selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been debugging the statement below for hours:

```
SELECT 
(
SELECT  t1.anotherColumn
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.aColumn=(1+ABS(Checksum(NewId()))%54)
) res, *
FROM 
(
SELECT TOP 200 * --PLEASE NOTICE HERE
FROM table2
)RESULT
```

and the problem is that always `res` contains the same value for each row. Now, if I change `200` that is highlighted in the query statement to any number below `176` it shows random rows of `table1` which is the desired result!

 Please note that the `54` has no effect on the results and it's there only because my table has 54 different values from 1 to 54 for `aColumn`.

 I have tried this query on different tables and this strange behavior is repeated!

Comment: This sounds like maybe the query optimizer is at work here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It seams that SQL Server is doing something behind the scene, and maybe that is the query optimizer, I'm not sure unless you know somehow. BTW, there should be a way to say thank you please do not do it for me!

Comment: You might need to force the engine to execute the first subquery for each result row. Try to add a dummy condition in the first subquery that makes it a correlative query, something like `AND result.id is not null`

Comment: Even I could replicate this issue

Comment: @Prdp Yes sure. That's why I used these temporary names. The result is the same for every table I tested.

Comment: Same result for this one as well `SELECT TOP 200 *,(
SELECT  t1.anotherColumn
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.aColumn=(1+ABS(Checksum(NewId()))%54)
) res 
FROM table1
`

Comment: I tried **correlating** the `sub-query` still same result `SELECT TOP 199 *, 
               (SELECT t1.anotherColumn
                FROM   table1 t1 
                WHERE  t1.aColumn= ( 1 + Abs(Checksum(Newid()))%54 ) 
                       AND ( t2.aColumn= t1.aColumn
                              OR 1 = 1 )) res 
FROM   table1 t2`

Comment: @Prdp  It seams that the logic is kept intact in your query but trincot's solution is not promising.

Comment: It seems to work reasonable up to TOP 176 rows :) More than 175 rows selection causes this issue, interesting..

Comment: @Eralper It becomes more interesting when we consider that our Operating systems and Sql servers may be different, and yet the results are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in results may be explained by the differences in query plans.

SQL optimizer can choose to use Table Spool / Lazy Spool operator. In this case, NEWID() is called once, the GUID is stored in the temp table and used for all other rows.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191221(v=sql.105).aspx

...
UPDATE:
the query plan can be fixed by adding below line at bottom:

```
option(use plan 
N'
<your XML plan>
')
```

To catch "good" XML plan, run

```
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON
```

and execute the query which shows expected result. Copy-paste it to OPTION(USE PLAN ...)

This solution works for me for the large number of rows (millions)

Comment: I had to remove the solution (GETDATE() > '2011-01-01') temporary as it does not always work when you pool too many records (thousands) AND when your have thousands rows in table1. I'll provide another one tomorrow if it is still needed. It really depends on the number of rows, so if your table is small, you can still use it.

Comment: Thanks.at least now I know the root of the problem. I'll try to make it work tomorrow as well cause yes sometimes the table becomes too big.

Comment: To fix a query plan, you can save "good" plan, and then re-use with "USE PLAN" Query Hint. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186954(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Wow incredible, Scratching my head for past 3 hours. Didn't thought about checking Execution plan. Good work

Comment: Can you explain why NEWID() is called once when Table Spool / Lazy Spool operator in execution plan

Comment: @Prdp, you can read http://sqldot.com/change-in-query-plan-can-affect-query-result-set-table-spool/ , but you won't find the full explanation as the work of sql optimizer is not documented. All that we can do here is to find a workaround (which is already given), or raise an incident with MS with hope they will improve it in the next release or SP.

Comment: @Prdp Personally, I think it is a bug in query optimizer. It's not ideal, it can make a wrong decision in many cases... that's why we have various query hints. In general, we need to avoid using them, but in such cases, it's good reason to put it to make the query stable.

Answer (score 2):

This will force the subquery to be reevaulated on every row and avoids the complicated random logic.

```
SELECT top 200
    (SELECT top 1 t1.anotherColumn from table1 t1 with( nolock ) where t2.t2Id is not null order by newid()  ) res, 
    *
FROM table2 t2
```

It works because newid() is already a random unique identifier and the comparison on table2 forces each row of table1 to be checked against the row in table2.